# Why do many liberal countries criminalize polygamy?

Tags: law, liberalism, marriage

Polygamy is a crime in many liberal countries (such [as all 27 countries of the European Union](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legality_of_polygamy)). It is theoretically victimless, however. Why then would a liberal country criminalize it?

Things I can think of:

- Polygamy is sexist. However, polygamy is not intrinsically sexist, and in most liberal countries, polyandry is just as illegal as polygyny.
- Polygamy can involve power differentials, historically involving men abusing women. While conceivable, the same can be said of prostitution, and prostitution is legal in many liberal countries.
- Moot/pointless because if the adults involved are all happy with the arrangement, they can live together without marrying. This is also conceivable, but there are legal advantages to marriage, so it's not entirely moot/pointless.

Related: [Why do many liberal countries criminalize incest?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/79918/why-do-many-liberal-countries-criminalize-incest) which asks about a similar illegal activity.

Comment: It would be nice if you took into account [polyamorous relations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polyamory) which, while lacking official status, may not be as criminalized.

Comment: Bigamy is, like, some kind of ugly boomer word. When it happens, keep an eye out for countries legalizing "polyamorous marriages."

Comment: @Obie2.0 what's with the "ugly boomer word"?  You could equally say that one gags at how many millennial Tinder profiles prattle on about their polyamory. ;-)

Comment: @ItalianPhilosophers4Monica - The point, made somewhat ironically, is that younger generations will think that the word polygamy sounds ugly because of the association with patriarchal societies, but will end up legalizing it under a different name because the *concept* dovetails well with a focus on marriage equality.

Comment: @Obie2.0 True dat.  FWIW it seems difficult to bring up `polyandry` legality by country info.  They keep on returning hits on `polygamy`.  Anyway, without more focus on distinguishing between the 2 this Q seems problematic.

Comment: https://www.healthline.com/health/relationships/polyamory-vs-polygamy#key-differences

Comment: Might want to also consider if yoy meant polygany, as that is more specific than polygamy.

Comment: "Polygamy is sexist. However, bigamy is not intrinsically sexist" - no, bigamy is just a special case of polygamy (with n=2).

Comment: @TrangOul I've edited the OP in response to your comment - I misunderstood one of the terms.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What purpose do anti-Polygamy laws serve?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/24813/what-purpose-do-anti-polygamy-laws-serve)  Or maybe that one should be closed as a duplicate of this, since there's more/better answers here?

Comment: @ItalianPhilosophers4Monica It’s my understanding that in may jurisdictions ‘polygamy’ is the legal term regardless of whether it is factually polygamy, polyandry, or some mixed form of polyamory. The laws were largely written at times where ‘polyamory’ was not a recognized word at all and polyandry was almost unheard of in ‘civilized’ society.

Comment: Here's a question for you: Under our modern system where gender is not a consideration in granting marriages, if we had a legal triple marriage, and one of the 3 partners dies, are the remaining 2 still married to each other? In other words, are all 3 married to each other, or are multiple people just married to the same person? I'm not looking for an answer, but just pointing out how decidedly non-simple allowing this would be.

Comment: Since it comes up, [there are polyandrous traditions/cultures in India](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polyandry_in_India).

Comment: @AustinHemmelgarn Sub 'polyamory' for any time I've used 'polyandry'.  I mean the lifestyle/stable - no-legal-effect - version of multi-partners, minus the legal marriage baggage related to 'polygamy/andry'.  Awww shucks, I get lost in all these multiple modern day words describing what used to be pretty simple:  shacking up with someone, or someones, else, minus the need to coin a word for every variation   Anyway, few countries in the liberal West bother bothering people re. the polyamory thing, which is transparent.  'polygamy' gets associated with deceit as deceit is usually involved

Comment: Because most (all) liberal countries aren't free at all. As Margaret Thatcher famously put it, _if you have to tell people you are, you are not_. In a free country only "issues" that absolutely must be regulated are regulated. Consenting adults relationships do not live up to that threshold. Hence these countries aren't free (liberal).

Comment: @d-b - But who decides what "must" be regulated?  Why are laws against kidnapping someone's kid be any more or less required than laws against exposing that kid to "obscene" things?  Or do you consider even having something like kidnapping laws to be non-free, and if so, what makes your "free" country not an anarchy?

Comment: @Bobson Your freedom ends where it violates my freedom. That is why kidnapping should be illegal but "exposing children to obscenities" probably shouldn't.

Comment: @d-b By your reasoning, someone's right to free speech ends when it violates a parent's freedom to raise their child the way they think is best. Or maybe it's _vice versa_ - a parent's freedom to raise the kid ends when it starts impinging on other people's free speech. They can't both be true, but both flow from your principle.  A society needs to decide which one should be prioritized, but no matter what, _someone's_ rights are going to be violated.  Which is why I take issue with trying to say that there are things that "must" be regulated - that's already a subjective value judgement.

Comment: @Bobson Please give a concrete example.

Comment: @d-b A concrete example of what, specifically?

Comment: @Bobson How freedom of speech can collide with parent's freedom to raise a child (Which isn't a freedom at all - parenting is a severe violation of children's freedom. It is easy to prove: if a parent "parented" a child that wasn't his/hers it would be a serious crime, kidnapping etc.). FYI, there are extremely few things that MUST be regulated. E.g., which side you drive on is an example of something that **doesn't** need to be regulated by the state.

Comment: @d-b I don't want to live in a world where cars are constantly veering to the side at high speed because they were on a collision course. I value the lives of the people not run over by enforcing a standard over your freedom.

Comment: @Caleth What are you talking about? A private road owner would most likely specify which side you drive on but the STATE doesn't have to tell the road owner that.

Comment: @d-b I also think that the state is the correct owner of roads. It's in the interest of non-road owners for there to be a monopoly on roads, because it's important that roads a) connect and b) go everywhere. Doubling up on roads is a massive waste of space

Comment: @Caleth The US state let the roads deteriorate during the 70s. Nuff said.

Comment: @d-b and the free market wouldn't? US cities are already filled with road. If you add free market competition, there won't be any city left. And even if roads were owned by private enterprise, it would *still* be a good idea for there to be a standardised side of the road to drive on, because like I mentioned before, an important part of roads is they join up

Comment: @Caleth You most likely would be able to choose road quality on a free market.

Comment: @d-b how? where's the space to permit the choice?

Comment: @Caleth Google Maps usually suggest 3 different itineraries when you search for driving directions between two points. Duh!

Comment: @d-b depends how close those two places are. How much road choice do you have leaving your home or arriving at your destination?

Comment: @Caleth Eeh no? I just looked up a destination less than 1 km away from my home (in city). I got three alternatives. If you drive less than a km road standard really doesn't matter as long as it is a road.

Comment: @d-b how much of those alternatives is shared between each of them? My point was there is only 1 option for the road outside your home. Adding choice to that means using even less space for anything but roads

Comment: @Caleth WIthin 100 meter or so, there are actually 4 alternative roads. Two crossing roads and two parallel. And that is typical. And my landlord owns the road outside the building, all the way to the next road. If the landlord abused that monopoly one wouldn't move to its house (or park 100 m away).

Answer (score 24, accepted):

## Old laws change when there is a call for it

This line of questioning "Why to liberal countries criminalise X" should take into account when that law was put in place and whether the countries were liberal at the time. Then we just have the question of "Why do countries have laws that haven't been updated yet?"

In the case of the UK the current law that criminalises bigamy was in [Section 57 of the Offences against the Person Act 1861](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/Vict/24-25/100/section/57):

> Whosoever, being married, shall marry any other person during the life of the former husband or wife, whether the second marriage shall have taken place in England or Ireland or elsewhere, shall be guilty of felony, and being convicted thereof shall be liable

Not a time when the UK would have been considered a liberal country (at least by today's standards). Until the populace sufficiently petitions a government to make changes to laws, they don't.

**Bigamy (and incest for that matter) simply aren't things that enough voters are interested in having legalised and plenty would be against**. No government wants to put through an unpopular law without sufficient backing. [A petition to legalise bigamy and polyamorous marriage currently only has 21 signatories out of a necessary 10,000 for a response and 100,000 it to be considered.](https://petition.parliament.uk/petitions/639004)

Comment: Sometimes old laws also change when a fresh look at them lets a constitutional court realize that they are unconstitutional...

Comment: No need to include incest.

Comment: @paulj This question is part of a set the OP asked, incest was one of the others.

Comment: In Ireland, the constitution states that marriage can occur between 2 people. An amendment would require referendum and that usually requires a big political push, and the appetite isn't there. Besides, assuming you could get that through (and there would be large resistance) there is, no doubt, a whole host of laws around marriage that work based on the assumption of 2 people (e.g. sharing tax credits, child-related laws, etc.) which would all have to be updated too - it would be a huge undertaking. So rather than a moral objection to polygamy it may be a practical one.

Answer (score 20):

Two reasons spring to mind:

1. Most (ostensibly) liberal countries are Western: European or colonized by European settlers. That means they were all (at some point) strongly steeped in one of the Abrahamic sects, specifically various forms of Christianity. The Christian faith sees marriage as a union between souls, and so anything that would disrupt the God-granted bond between two souls — extra-marital affairs, divorce, and yes, add-on marriages — was forbidden as a sin. Even as religiosity has declined in the West, that attitude has persisted. It doesn't help that the those modern(ish) groups which have tried to rehabilitate polygamy have all been schismatic Christian sects or blatant cults, and thus roundly criticized by the mainstream.
2. Polygamy as a historical practice was markedly aristocratic. Multiple wives were the province of the wealthy and politically powerful, whether as a status symbol, an effort to maximize the possibility of male heirs, or as a means to create political or economic alliances. As such, it didn't have much effect on the lower classes, aside from some natural salacious interest. But as the ideals of Liberalism took hold — and yes, before someone else says it, 16th century thinkers likely would have lumped women under 'property rights' — the concept of polygamy became somewhat distasteful. Partly (I think) this was a dismissive contempt that polygamy was a decadent activity of pervy aristocrats or exotic foreigners. But partly I think it was the growing realization that women are only 51% of the population, and if every Freeman Jack set his mind on multiple wives, simple math would lead to massive bloodshed.

Few cultures have ever seriously considered the issue of polyandry, since a woman with multiple male parters was almost universally considered shameful or sinful. But, you know, this is all speculation.

Comment: The first argument makes sense, but it doesn't clarify why extra-marital affairs and divorce are nowadays legal, but add-on marriages are still a crime.

Comment: @Evargalo: Divorce is legal courtesy of Henry VIII and subsequently the Protestant reformation. Henry VII was king just before the onset of the Classical Liberal era, most to the CL thinkers were protestants of one sort or another, and the concept of divorce jibed well with Liberal ideals of personal freedom. Note that Ireland (a staunchly Catholic nation) only legalized abortion in 1995.

Comment: @Evargalo: Extra-marital affairs are legal (as I see it) because — despite being universally despised — they are hard to adjudicate. Wikipedia's [Adultery in English Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adultery_in_English_law) points out that jurisdiction waffled between secular and ecclesiastical courts, and punishments ranged from death sentences to fines for men and disfigurement for women to public or private acts of religious penitence to civil torts. Ultimately they settled (1923) on saying that the only legal consequences of adultery was giving grounds for divorce.

Comment: Judaism most definitely allowed polygamy **for 1000 years after the start of Christianity** https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gershom_ben_Judah#Synod_and_bans (who got monogamy from the Romans).

Answer (score 20):

**Stability of the society**

When a high-status man takes two wives, a lower-status man gets no wife. Those men, denied access to life's most stabilizing and civilizing institution, are unfairly disadvantaged and often turn to behaviors like crime and violence. There are generally higher levels of rape, kidnapping, murder, assault robbery and fraud in polygynous cultures ([source](https://www.eurekalert.org/news-releases/868370)). Societies become inherently unstable when effective sex ratios reach something like 120 males to 100 females, such that a sixth of men are surplus commodities in the marriage market ([source](https://www.jonathanrauch.com/jrauch_articles/the-problem-with-polygamy/)). That's not a big number.

This is not very directly related to Christianity. Even before Christianity became the official religion of the Roman Empire, Diocletian and Maximian passed strict anti-polygamy laws in 285 AD.

Comment: It's worth pointing out that in societies where men do routinely take many wives, they are often characterised by high rates of military action which adjusts the sex ratio (and polygamy becomes a functional response to how many men must be allocated to war, without leaving a surplus of unwived men).

Comment: You're equating polygamy (being married to multiple partners) with polygyny (a man being married to multiple women). Historically, polygyny may have been the dominant form of polygamy, but this is also strongly tied to oppression of women and forced marriages. In an equal society where all combinations of polygamy are allowed, the bad effects listed wouldn't really apply. (Although given that the question asks why society is that way it is, historical reasons play a big part.)

Comment: @NotThatGuy There is a reason why historically polygamy was one man+multiple women and not one woman+multiple men - and it has nothing to do with oppresion of women...One man can have children with multiple women, but one woman cannot have children with multiple men (at least at once). And since desire for offspring is one of the strongest biological urges(and wanting being in a relationship when you don't have a chance of having your offspring is kinda a good way to NOT pass on those traits).So that kind of polygamy will still introduce same instability into your society as having single men.

Comment: @Negdo Technically a woman can, as there is such a thing as (heteropaternal) superfecundation (two distinct ova fertilized at essentially the same time, possibly by different men; if it's the same father you get what we call fraternal twins).  It's pretty rare, though (maybe on the 2-3% level amongst women involved in paternity disputes, so a sample likely biased towards a higher rate), so on a practical level your statement is correct.  But it's nice to remember that biology is weird and there's a lot of variety in twins.

Comment: @Negdo: I'd describe the reason differently: no matter how many women a man sleeps with, any woman will know whether she is the mother of any child sired by her husband.  If a woman sleeps with multiple men, however, none of them will have any way of knowing whether they are the father of any of her children.

Comment: @supercat, on the other hand, knowing the father only really matters for patrilinear inheritance and such. A matrilinear society wouldn't need to care that much who the father was. Also, I'm not sure it matters that much if the men can't know for sure if a child is theirs: they have some interest in taking part in childcare if there's a chance the child is theirs, and if they also have multiple partners, it's a just a case of playing more hands with smaller bets, so to say. Even in monogamous societies, men can't know for sure if a child is theirs...

Comment: And well, then there's the question of if the society even knows there is just a single biological father. Maybe the men are all fathers of the child.

Comment: *are unfairly disadvantaged and often turn to behaviors like crime and violence* => why don't we see this in China? https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/78297/is-china-suffering-increased-crime-levels-or-reduced-gdp-growth-from-having-17. I suspect that it's not actually a problem in practice because the men most likely to commit crimes are also most likely to be attractive to women.

Comment: @ilkkachu I imagine humans had already figured that 1:1 relationship before recorded history, and likely even before they would be considered humans, or perhaps even mammals. Way, way back.

Comment: @supercat that's in the past though. These days there are paternity tests.

Answer (score 13):

A partial answer is that, in the US, much of the support for bigamy laws came from opposition to child marriage.

The biggest examples of bigamy in the US has been FLDS members - that is fundamentalist offshoots of the LDS (mormon) Church.

While the LDS church now forbids polygamy, they used to support it (its been argued they only gave it up to avoid persecution). Not every group agreed with these reforms.

Within these FLDS groups, polygamy takes the form of polygany (one husband, multiple wives), with women being "married off" young, usually to much older men. With the women having no say in the matter (or virtually anything else). It is a very barbaric practice and culture.

I don't know if they're still around, but Tapestry Against Polygamy was a group that opposed polygamy for that reason.

Comment: Did you really want to write that it was _support_ for bigamy laws what came from opposition to child marriage?

Comment: @Ángel i think by 'bigamy laws' they mean laws against bigamy. So support for outlawing bigamy.

Answer (score 5):

Because this is how their people want to visualize themselves.

In liberal countries, state acts are formed based on public opinion. People form an idea, then they gather as a group, then create pressure on the government to legalize it. Then public representatives take it to the parliament and the act gets passed.

**For example,**

1. Same-sex marriage in the Netherlands was legalized a decade ago because people wanted it.
2. Germany is in favor of LGBTQ right, because the people want it.
3. People in some countries wanted Marijuana to be legalized, so Marijuana is legal now in many countries.

**Why don't people want it to be allowed?**

For cultural reasons! Culture is developed on the basis of history and anthropology.

For instance, Western culture suggests women should wear shorter clothes than men. This is unintuitive given that women have more private parts than men. However, the West certainly has their own reasoning which I would not want to dispute.

Similarly, Western culture allows men to have multiple sex partners while they cannot have multiple wives.

If these people can form a sufficiently large group and start a movement in favor of polygamy, the state would surely decriminalize it in the end.

Comment: *It's not allowed because people don't want it to be allowed* - ... okay, but why don't people want it to be allowed? It seems you've just described how a democracy works.

Comment: @NotThatGuy, *why don't people want it to be allowed?* --- Cultural reasons. Culture is developed on the basis of history and anthropology.

Comment: That...'s still not saying much. What cultural reasons? Which parts of history and anthropology is this based on?

Comment: @NotThatGuy, check the edit.

Comment: Not entirely: see James K answer. Allowing more then two people to enter a marriage means solving a lot of 'technical' legal problems, and writing specific laws for specific cases. Not just for future 'marriages' but also for existing and maybe even past marriages - what is grandma receives a pension based on the pension plan of grandpa who is dead. Now what if grandma remarries, her spouse marries another two people, one of them marries more people, some of them get divorced, and so on. Who of all these people will get some of that pension?

Comment: @Ivana, *Allowing more then two people to enter a marriage means solving a lot of 'technical' legal problems, and writing specific laws for specific cases.* --- Many Muslim-majority countries allow having more than one wife and they are facing no legal or systemic issues. James K is saying the existing system cannot cope with polygamy. This is because the existing system doesn't want to change.

Comment: @user366312 i wrote an answer to address that elephant in the room: current 'liberal' marriage law is for 2 equal consenting adults, marriage law in countries allowing polygamy is for 1 man and some women or female children who have no rights or say in the matter. This takes all questions of property and custody over children out of the equation.

Answer (score 4):

It's not very romantic but technically marriages are just small scale private unlimited corporations. Meaning a company of 2 people sharing risks, profits and mutual responsibilities. And it's a financial union that is often subsidized by the state.

So it's not a victimless crime, you potentially cheat on the state and on your spouse who now has to cover for your failures but isn't profiting from your profits that you generate with another spouse.

So it's not just polyamory but there are also quite some financial and legal considerations involved in that.

Comment: This only explains why current marriage laws are unsuitable for more than two members. But you could reform laws to properly and fairly scale with ≥2 members.

Comment: Really, this perspective is a strong argument that it should be simple for a legal change to allow for polygamy, since currently more than two people can found and run a business. If a marriage is a financial structure, then that structure can be adapted to be like other financial structures.

Comment: this also seems to imply or presume some sort of an equal partnership, which a marriage always hasn't been (esp. if the wife is considered the man's "property"), and also with prenups being a thing, the part about a financial union need not be a thing. And if there's no financial structure, there should be no obstacle in taking another partner to the marriage.

Comment: @Michael not easily.  going beyond 2 people is a giant leap and introduces numerous problems and circumstances that simply do not exist when you are only dealing with 2 people.  Mathematically, with two people you have only 1 interaction (AB), with three people you have 4 (AB, BC, AC, ABC).  It's an expenitional problem, and an utter nightmare to try compared to the already massive problems a normal divorce involves.  Which is why there's basically no historical examples (even in polygamous societies, who only had 1 or 2 of the people having any real rights in divorce)

Comment: Cheating on a spouse or falsifying legal relationships is a crime in itself. The context in which that crime occurs (if marital) is not a crime.

Answer (score 1):

### Polygamy was a target of a major political movement

No answer to this question is complete without mention of the notable **[Morrill anti-Bigamy Act of 1862](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morrill_Anti-Bigamy_Act)**, the **[Edmunds Act of 1882](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edmunds_Act)** and the **[Edmunds-Tucker Act of 1887](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edmunds%E2%80%93Tucker_Act)**.

The express purpose of those acts was to restrict the religious practice of plural marriage and other activities by members of [the Church of Jesus Christ of Latter-day Saints](https://www.churchofjesuschrist.org/?lang=eng), who at that time had largely emigrated to the Utah Territory. The acts criminalized polygamy and enforced sanctions against those who practiced it or taught it, even to the extent of disincorporating the church and endeavoring to make its founders and practitioners felons.

The notion of polygamy being evil or reprehensible began to be more widespread and vehement in the United States some decades earlier as a direct response to the founding of this church and the practice of its religion, which did involve a number of cases of and teachings about polygamy. The indignation against polygamy became galvanized into a mainstream political movement when the **[1856 Republican National Convention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_twin_relics_of_barbarism)** advanced the notion that it was a "barbaric relic" as a contemptible twin to **human slavery**, that had to be eradicated.

The founder of the Church of Jesus Christ of Latter-day Saints, Joseph Smith, had just been [assassinated twelve years prior in 1844 by a mob in Illinois](https://knowhy.bookofmormoncentral.org/knowhy/why-was-joseph-smith-murdered), in part spurred on by rumors of polygamy and myriad libelous claims against him.
After his death, the saints spent two years preparing to move West. They were headed for what was then Mexican territory to [find a refuge](https://www.familysearch.org/en/wiki/Latter-day_Saint_Emigration_and_Immigration) beyond the borders of the United States where they could practice their religion without being mobbed and murdered for their beliefs.

The geopolitical aspect of this change did not last long; the Mexican Cession through the [Guadalupe-Hidalgo Treaty of 1848](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mexican_Cession) brought them once again within the borders of the United States, subject to its politics and policies.

What is ironic about the "twin relics" claim of the Republican Convention is that Smith was assassinated not long after he began campaigning for president of the United States; **[notably his platform included the abolition of slavery](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joseph_Smith_1844_presidential_campaign)**.
He was the first US presidential candidate to be assassinated. Some historians opine that his anti-slavery stance may have contributed significantly towards the impetus for his assassination. The later assassination of Abraham Lincoln over this same subject lends credibility to that hypothesis. *Abraham* Lincoln is widely hailed as the father of the Republican party.

On the basis of this understanding, did the two alleged "barbarisms" really belong together?

### Relation of anti-polygamy movement to Christianity

The claim in at least one other answer that polygamy was disfavored in Christian societies ignores some very important facts about the Christian religion:

- Abraham was a polygamist (Genesis 16).
- Jacob was a polygamist (Genesis 29).
- Moses may have been a polygamist (Numbers 12).
- Hundreds and thousands of reputable practitioners of ancient Christianity, including during the mortal ministry of Jesus Christ, were polygamists.
- The law that God gave to Moses permitted polygamy, but forbade adultery and pagan marriages.

The idea that polygamy is unchristian or incompatible with Christianity or with any of the Abrahamic religions frankly denies the very Foundation of Christianity. To do so one must discredit the "father of the faithful" (Romans 4:11) and deny the covenants God made with the patriarchs and are ubiquitously affirmed in those volumes of Scripture.

### Edit: Precursor bigamy legislation in the United Kingdom

There is a noteworthy law enacted in the United Kingdom, the [Offences against the Person Act of 1861](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/Vict/24-25/100/section/57), that precedes the Morrill Act by one year, which states that bigamy shall be a criminal offense, together with many other criminal reforms. This is not the oldest anti-polygamy or anti-bigamy law on the books; legislation against polygamy appears to be as old as the late Roman Empire. (The Romans were actually a rare exception to the norm of polygamy in nearly all ancient cultures. Excepting times of war or
the privilege of potentates, we expect monogamous marriage to be the most common form of marital union due to simple mathematics).
[The table on Wikipedia that you reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legality_of_polygamy#To_outlaw_polygamy) in your question shows the 1862 act as nearly the oldest "notable" example in modern times.

### Modern Treatment of Polygamy

Fast forward to today: the State of Utah recently [decriminalized adultery, fornication, and sodomy](https://www.washingtonexaminer.com/news/utah-decriminalizes-sex-outside-of-marriage).
For a long time, fornication was a misdemeanor in Utah, while polygamy was still classed as a felony.
That has changed recently too, although apparently polygamy is still not treated with parity compared to extramarital relations, and perhaps never has been (enforcement of laws in the US against adultery, fornication, etc. has been a rarity). With the rapidly changing legal landscape, and questions continuing to arise about what will and will not be enforced, it is not yet clear exactly how the treatment of polygamy will compare to the treatment of sex crimes in the future. Based on the historic and present designations and enforcement rates, it appears that the old stigma is still at least somewhat in force, and polygamy may still be being treated as "more barbaric" than many forms of extramarital sexual licentiousness.

You are correct that polygamy is victimless since it is consensual and involves as strong a vow as monogamous marriage to maintain the relationship and commitment to provide for spouse(s) and children. Extramarital sex lacks these protections for partners and children and so are far from victimless.

**Footnote on comparison to incest**

There is not much comparison between incest and polygamy other than their illegality.
One reason why incest is scientifically wrong is the extremely high likelihood of children inheriting debilitating genetic anomalies due to inbreeding. This has been proven to be caused by parents sharing a deleterious mutation.
In the days of Adam and Eve, marrying one's sibling [carried practically no genetic risks because few or no genetic errors had yet accumulated.](https://answersingenesis.org/adam-and-eve/could-2-people-populate-planet-7-billion-people/)
The Mosaic law forbade incest, but this cannot be used to condemn the children of Adam and Eve because Moses was 2500 years and many generations removed from Adam and Eve, and there was sufficient genetic differentiation by that time to make the risks of inheriting a redundant defect nontrivial, hence the introduction of a new law regarding it.

Comment: https://politics.stackexchange.com/a/80441/8334 <- the current law against bigamy in the UK was passed in 1861, as referenced in an answer to this very question.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the already insightful answers, the reason we need a law against polygamy is marriage has a legal status, and if a person were to be married to someone extra that would be cheating, not just in the relationship, but also legally and financially.

Now imagine opinions start changing and voters turn to favouring polygamy. In that case we would seek to decriminalize it and find a way to make marriage law apply to any number of people.

Now the problem is there are no examples anywhere of acceptable polygamy laws, that is laws allowing polygyny/andry among equals.

In the countries that have polygyny women are considered half-humans at best. Men always get custody of children after a divorce, women cannot get divorced or remarried as easily as men, women often have no property. This combined with the fact that the laws allowing only poly**gyny** makes it a easy to write the law: marriage is one man and a number of women who have no say in anything.

Comment: If not having examples of laws elsewhere allowing both polygyny and polyandry, is one of the best arguments against it, then I'd say the arguments against it are extremely weak.

Comment: I'm pretty sure your first two paragraphs are already covered by [James K's answer](https://politics.stackexchange.com/a/80437/20220).

Comment: Cheating in what sense? There is nothing that can be cheated in financial and dutiful obligations.
"There are no examples anywhere of acceptable polygamy laws" - could you cite some historical evidence for this claim? What of people who succeeded historically in polygamous relationships, such as Abraham and Jacob?
"marriage is one man and a number of women who have no say in anything."
This is a non sequitur. What do women want say over? Anything except exclusive control over her husband is on the table.
These same arguments might also apply to marriage in general depending on the culture.

Comment: The "cheating" argument might have more bite if it weren't risking conflating with "cheating" in a relationship sense. Language specifying what you mean by the legal/financial sense, and using a term other than cheating might help the answer get its points across (assuming you mean things like taking advantage of areas where rules are set for 2 people - like further reducing tax burden via marriage incentives that were defined for 2).

Comment: @bharring Taxes, pensions, inheritance.

Comment: @pygosceles "What do women want say over?" Divorce, child custody, additional husbands. Also "There is nothing that can be cheated in financial and dutiful obligations": what about pensions? Mine covers my partner. If he gets an additional partner, should my pension now also cover that person? Their children? That would be a pretty big overhaul of the system.

Comment: Certainly a concern, I just think it'd be better represented if you didn't use the term cheating.

Comment: @Ivana The previously existing laws against no-fault divorce were good laws. Polygamy if legally accepted is by definition not adultery, so grounds for a divorce could not exist if there were not infidelity in the situation. Having a "say" in divorce then is meaningless.
Alimony and child support law allows a woman to send government agents with guns to compel her husband to deliver sufficient resources to meet her and her children's material needs.
What if she wants more?
These sound like concerns having more to do with financial control and pettiness than anyone's rights being violated.

Comment: Some of those arguments only work in theory. In theory, government ensures child support. In practice, an estimated 43% is actually paid currently https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.cbsnews.com/amp/news/10-billion-in-child-support-payments-going-uncollected-according-to-estimates/ .

Comment: The concerns you brought up sound financial because you brought up the financial concerns. They sound petty because you haven't had to raise a child with a deadbeat dad and poor job. While spousal support is a confounding matter (does it attach only to the single-gender-member? All current marriage members? All current and former?), it's one of very many.

Comment: Arguing specifics about a hypothetical set of polygamy rules can be interesting, but when discussing public acceptance of it, the preexisting forms of polygamy are more relevant than hypothetical. And the most widespread form of polygamy at least in the US is FLDS-style chattel woken. They have no real say in their own lives. That's not hypothetical. One could differentiate, but they'd have to be clear.

Comment: @bharring "better represented if you didn't use the term cheating" I used 'cheating' both as a joke but also as i was hoping to underline that marriage is not only a romantic relation between two people but also a contract between those two people and society/institutions. May not work as well as i hoped